# Postfix with two arguments

Tags: output-formatting

This must be a duplicate but I can't find any related post. 
I want to pass two arguments to a function using postfix syntax like

```
f[a_,b_]:=a+b;
1,2//f
```

More generally, can somebody explain to me in better detail how I can use these kind of constructions: `@f` , `~~f~~`, and `//f`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let me start with the second question first as it is more direct.  You can see for yourself how these inputs work:

```
f @ x
x ~f~ y
x // f
```

> ```
> f[x]
> f[x, y]
> f[x]
> ```

The first and third only work with a single argument.  Similar to but distinct from the first is `@@` which is shorthand for [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html), and it allows:

```
f @@ {x, y}
```

> ```
> f[x, y]
> ```

Here the Head `List` is replaced with `f`.  For more clarity see: [Scan vs. Map vs. Apply](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46238/121)

With the single-argument forms you can use `Sequence` to insert multiple arguments, but *only* if the function (`f`) does not have the Attribute [`SequenceHold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SequenceHold.html) or [`HoldAllComplete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldAllComplete.html):

```
f @ Sequence[x, y]
Sequence[x, y] // f
```

> ```
> f[x, y]
> f[x, y]
> ```

And an example of where this will *not* work:

```
Rule @ Sequence[x, y]
```

> Rule::argr: Rule called with 1 argument; 2 arguments are expected. >>
>
> ```
> Rule[Sequence[x, y]]
> ```

If you wish to use a multi-argument function with `//` application you can make it a parametrized, SubValues, or operator form function, all meaning essentially the same thing.  See:

- [Define parameterized function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7999/define-parameterized-function/8003#8003)
- [V10's Operator Forms - what are they good for?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56504/121)

A very simple example:

```
f[a__][x_] := g[a, x]
```

Now:

```
y // f[x]
```

> ```
> g[x, y]
> ```

```
x // f[1, 2, 3]
```

> ```
> g[1, 2, 3, x]
> ```

See the first bulleted link above for more examples and theory.

Related:

- [Is it possible to insert arguments into functions when they're used like Function@ or //Function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6955/121)
- [Syntax for prefix mode with multiple arguments using @ shorthand](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5432/121)

Comment: Note that you can always use `x // f[#, ...]&` if you need to supply extra arguments like in `Table[{i, 2^i}, {i, 24, 0, -1}] // TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> {None, {"i", "2^i"}}] &`

Comment: @lkuty Oh yes, that's a very useful pattern.  It is mentioned in an answer to one of the questions I linked: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6957/121.  I make use of it quite often, e.g. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/136196/121

Answer (score 7):

(Just answering the first question.  Others have answered the second question thoroughly.)

It's worth mentioning that you can do

```
{x,y} // (f @@ #) &
```

> f[x,y]

(No parentheses needed, but I added them for clarity.)

You could even make your own function to do this (slightly) more compactly, especially if you have trouble remembering the `@`'s and `#`'s :

```
ClearAll[pf]
pf[ argList_, f_ ] := f @@ argList
```

Then you can do what you want using an infix operator:

```
{x,y} ~pf~ f
```

> f[x,y]

#### **Edit:**

Lately I've taken to writing my first example above as

```
{x,y} // Apply[f]
```

or

```
{x,y} // Apply@f
```

which I fine somewhat more readable, particularly when there are other pure functions involved.  Note that this uses the operator form of [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html).

Answer (score 3):

According to my basic understand of these notations:

For infix notation, the function must be a binary operator, e.g.

```
g[x_, y_] := x^2 - y^2;
```

Then

```
5~g~2
```

Gives

```
25-4=21
```

For postfix notation, the function must take one argument

```
f[{x_,y_}]:=x^2-y^2
```

So

```
{5,2}//f
```

gives 21