# Can we pass arguments to "//"?

Tags: functions, arguments

For example, we can pass 3 to function N as `N[Pi,3]`, and we can use the form `Pi // N` to apply N to Pi, but missed the argument.

Can we pass the argument to the "//" form?

Comment: try `Pi//N[#,3]&`?

Comment: Yeah, that works.

Comment: you can also use `Infix` form:  `Pi~N~3`

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Postfix with two arguments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56882/postfix-with-two-arguments)